# Questions about my wifi card

Tags: wireless

I wanted to find out my wifi card as I did a fresh Ubuntu installation. I don't think Ubuntu by default installed the correct drivers.

So I typed in terminal:

`sudo lshw -C network`

and this was the result:

```
*-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:56400000-56403fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 88:ae:1d:d1:71:eb
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:52410000-52410fff memory:52400000-5240ffff memory:52420000-5243ffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 00:26:82:cd:cc:39
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.8.0-19-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

1. Now my question is how to install proper drivers for the card?
2. If proper drivers are installed how to find out?
3. Thirdly I want to know if my card supports monitoring mode, promiscuous mode.
4. Will it work with Aircrack-ng ?

I am asking this because Aircrack-ng does not have a list of supported cards.

Comment: Could you include an `lspci -nn` and an `rfkill list` as well?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open "Additional Driver"  option , it will search the drivers that are required for your PC and Card to support .
2. After that a list of driver being show , here you can select the driver according to you manufacturing company and Broadcom STA wireless Driver work fine with all cards.
3. You can find the package --->

   ```
    sudo lspci
    sudo dpkg --get-selections
   ```
4. for Aircrack-ng support please check the link for supported Brand/Manufactures

   http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatibility_drivers